# How to choose an option in html select on login and show's inside application

Tags: php, laravel, frontend, backend, laravel-blade

I need on [login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjpd4.png) choose an option and after user's choose show's on header of application. I created a middleware for it but I dont know how to use it.

Is correct use middleware for it? If not, how to do?

Middleware

```
class AnoLetivo {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->anoletivo) {
            return view('header')->with('anoletivo', $request->anoletivo);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

header.blade.php

```
<span class="label label-warning" title="Ano Letivo Corrente">{{ $anoletivo }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think use middleware is a good idea , it like "a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application", you should read the [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware) first .
Beside the request has all the input text or choose in controller if you want to print whatever you want just call it

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)